# Configure Tasks Runner using Gulp in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: macos, gulp, task, visual-studio-code

I have created default Web project from Yo library.
I have error in Visual Studio Code on Mac when run command Configure Tasks Runner:
"Unable to create the 'tasks.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder ([object Object])."

gulpfile.js

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
'use strict';
var gulp = require("gulp"),
  rimraf = require("rimraf"),
  concat = require("gulp-concat"),
  cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
  ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
  merge = require('merge'),
  project = require("./project.json");

var paths = {
  webroot: "./" + project.webroot + "/",
  tsSource: './TypeScript/app/**/*.ts',
  tsOutput: "./" + project.webroot + '/scripts/app/',
  tsDef: "./TypeScript/definitions/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

var tsProject = ts.createProject({
    declarationFiles: true,
    noExternalResolve: false,
    module: 'AMD',
    removeComments: true
});

gulp.task("clean:js", function(cb) {
  rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function(cb) {
  rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function() {
  gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], {
      base: "."
    })
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function() {
  gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task('ts-compile', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(paths.tsSource)
                    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tsDef)),
        tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tsOutput))
    ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['ts-compile'], function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.tsDef, ['ts-compile']);
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

Comment: did you get it resolved?

Comment: When I saw your question I run mentioned command again and it failed. But after updating VS code to version 0.10.16 error disappear ;) Now I can continue work with programming on mac os x ;)

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your question I run mentioned command again and it failed. But after updating VS code to version 0.10.16 error disappear ;) Now I can continue work with programming on mac os x ;)